# What will become of Ar-Pharazôn and his men?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium

I've been reading through a book (I think it was The Complete Guide to Middle-earth by Robert Foster) and I'm uncertain what the ultimate fate of the Numenorians who invaded Aman will be?

Ar-Pharazôn made a huge error in invading Aman with a massive force of men, but they were buried under mountains if I remember correctly. Is this punishment forever or will they be able to redeem themselves?

Will they be allowed to take part in the final music with the rest of men or will they remain trapped forever?

Comment: Does your link specify that Ar-Pharazôn will take part in the music?

Comment: Tolkien doesn't say so I don't specify.

Answer (score 3):

Why do you think they will have any different fate from any other men? Sauron lied to Ar-Pharazôn when he said that the Númenóreans could gain immortality by invading Aman. There's no indication that that's the truth; indeed we're told that Frodo and the other mortals who sailed West at the end of LoTR will simply gain peace until the end of their natural lives, not that those lives would be in any way extended.

So, I don't think there's any reason to believe that the men who were buried under a mountain would not be dead, exactly as any other men who suffered a similar fate anywhere else.

Comment: That's what I would assume, but as Eru Ilúvatar is the only one who can supersede the gift of men, and because it was his intervention as punishment I did not know if they were dead or not.

Comment: @PatrickDeveloper - the text in the Silmarillion states that "they lie imprisoned in the Caves of Forgotten, until the Last Battle and the Day of Doom".  This goes back virtually unchanged to the first version of the Fall of Númenor in the early/mid 1930s, and Tolkien doesn't say whether they're imprisoned dead or imprisoned alive.  We know they'll return at the Last Battle, but Tolkien doesn't say which side they'll fight on, nor does he say anything of their fate afterwards.  The text as I quote it is literally all that there is.